# How to alter dependency file format generated by gnu make?

Tags: makefile, gnu

I would like to alter the format of the dependency file from:

```
src/foo.obj : \
src/foo.h \
src/bar.h
```

to something like this :

```
src/foo.obj : src/foo.h \
src/foo.obj : src/bar.h
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can use `awk`, but I don't really see the advantage of doing so

Comment: In fact, the file contents is generated by the compiler and (usually) never altered by make.

Comment: In fact in fact, the "desired output" requested above is a syntax error and will fail.  I assume the author didn't mean to include the backslash at the end of the first line.